# Keep getting NullPointerExceptions when attempting to call getWritableDatabase()

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to the Android framework and I can't get past first base with SQLite.

I'm trying to build a very simple application that has a EditText search box, which when a key is pressed performs a Like %word% search on a SQLite database for for the text entered in the EditText box, and displays the results in a ListView.

N.B. the below code included debugging and commented code, sorry I haven't got round to cleaning it up yet.

The Activate is

```
public class sustainable_fish extends Activity {

private String keycodeToAscii(int arg2){

    String retvar = "";

    switch(arg2){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A: retvar = "a";break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B: retvar = "b";break;
```

snipped, but you get the idea.

```
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET: retvar = ")";break;
    default: retvar = ""; break;
    };
    return retvar;

}



 Context that = getApplicationContext();
 fishDB dh = new fishDB(getApplicationContext());


private OnKeyListener search = new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Cursor cur = null;
        String searchData;
        EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fish_search);
        CharSequence edit_text_value = myEditText.getText();
        searchData = edit_text_value.toString();
        searchData = searchData + keycodeToAscii(arg2.getKeyCode() );
        Log.d("onKey", "searchData = "+searchData);
        /*
        Commented out because as the database doesn't work, so theirs no point just yet searching.

        cur = fish.search(searchData);
        if (cur != null)
        {
            String[] displayFields = new String[] {cur.getString(2),
                    cur.getString(1)};

            int[] displayViews = new int[] { R.id.fish_rank,
                    R.id.fish_name};

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(that, 
                    R.layout.text_list, cur, 
                    displayFields, displayViews);

            ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 
        */

        return false;
    }

};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fish_search);
   searchBar.setOnKeyListener(search); 

}

}
```

The SQLite database is handled by fishDB

```
  public class fishDB {

 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fish.db3";
 public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private SQLiteDatabase database;
 private Context myContext;
 private static boolean booFirstrun = false;

 fishDB(Context inContext){
     myContext = inContext;
     OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(myContext);
     Log.w("fishDB", "Called OpenHelper");

             // Here be the problem...

     database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

 }

 public boolean firstRun(){
    return booFirstrun;
 }


   private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS = "create table feeds (feed_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
           + "title text not null, url text not null);";

          OpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
             Log.w("OpenHelper", "Called superconstructor");
            }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
              try {
              Log.w("OpenHelper", "in onCreate");
              booFirstrun = true;
              Log.w("OpenHelper", "set booFirstrun");
              db.beginTransaction();
              Log.w("OpenHelper", "db.beginTransaction");
              try {
                  // Create tables and test data
                  db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS);
                  Log.w("OpenHelper", "execSQL");
                  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                  Log.w("OpenHelper", "setTransactionSuccessful");
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
                  throw e;
              } finally {
                  db.endTransaction();
              }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("OpenHelper", e.toString() );
              } finally {
              Log.w("OpenHelper", "out of onCreate");
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             Log.w("OpenHelper", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
             onCreate(db);
          }
       } 
 }
```

Now every time "database = helper.getWritableDatabase();" is called the app crashes with a NullPointerException. I've managed to trace the error to the onCreate method of OpenHelper and the "db.beginTransaction();" line.

What am I missing?

Comment: Also for reference (mine if no one elses) `db.endTransaction();` causes the onCreate to fail (and fail silently) causing a runtime error in `OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(myContext);` and not writing any tables to the database (and so causing an additional SQLException on the next call). Hope this stop's some one else wasting a day tracking it down (or just me next time I write a Database class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you do not need to start transaction at onCreate method of the helper. Try removing everything from the method except `db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS);`

**Update**: I was able to repeat the problem.

Move fishDb field initialization to the `onCreate()` method of activity after that error disappears. It looks like it is not good idea to start db initialization before the onCreate is invoked.

So instead of

```
fishDB fishDb = new fishDB(getApplicationContext());
```

do

```
fishDB fishDb;

onCreate(){
  super.onCreate();
  fishDb = new fishDB(getApplicationContext());
  .... //init listener, query db etc..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but sadly it doesn't fit the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. and yes that's fixed it, I was so obsessed with it being a problem in the db class it never occurred to me it may be to do with initial call.
N.B. to others "Context that = getApplicationContext();" also doesn't work because you can't call getApplicationContext() outside of a procedure. use "Context that = this;" instead.

Comment: I am sorry, but is there any other work around, cause I still have the same problem. I have the open database calls in an async request that gets called after super.onCreate(stuff)

Answer (score 2):

The following code is derived from the original Android NotePad tutorial:

```
public class FishDb {

private static final String TAG = "FishDb";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS = "create table feeds (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
       + "title text not null, url text not null);";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fish.db3";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "feeds";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feeds");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

// ... The helper methods
}
```

You would instantiate in your Activities onCreate() and possibly open() in onResume(), close() on onPause():

```
private FishDb mDbHelper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new FishDb(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
        mDbHelper.open();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("onResume", e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{
        mDbHelper.close();
    }  catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("onPause", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Use "_id" instead of "feed_id" for primary key.

Comment: Also, be sure to check out the Android docs on using the core Search: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html