# SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase problem

Tags: java, android, sqlite

EDIT: I believe i may have found the problem. I need to work on my SmartDBHelper class. Will do this and post the results here.

EDIT: Found a link to someone who is having similar problem. Will be checking this to see if it fixes asap. [Another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489427/keep-getting-nullpointerexceptions-when-attempting-to-call-getwritabledatabase)

EDIT: Updated to reflect some changes made suggested by some of the posters. Problem is still occurring.

THE POST BELOW:

My application need to be able to write to the sqlite3 database that is on the android from 2 different events. One of my events is writing to the database just fine. When the second event tries to write to the database the attached error occurs. I have no clue why this is happening or how to fix it. I have tried numerous things the past couple hours and googled a ton. Can someone please view the code i have below and let me know what you think?

If you need any more information please let me know asap.

Thanks in advance!

```
//This is the sqliteopenhelper i created
public class SmartDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "smart_lite_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME = "user_notify_data";
    private static final String HR_TABLE_NAME = "user_hr_data";
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME + 
        " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
        "userresponse INTEGER, " + 
        "notifytime INTEGER);";
    private static final String DATA_TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + HR_TABLE_NAME +
        " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "hr INTEGER, " +
        "act INTEGER, " +
        "timestamp INTEGER);";      

    public SmartDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("smartdbhelper", "before creation");
        db.execSQL(NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.v("smartdbhelper", "middle creation");
        db.execSQL(DATA_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.v("smartdbhelper", "after creation");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

---

```
//This is the part that is working CORRECTLY
public class DataNotificationSurvey extends Activity {
    private SmartDBHelper dBHelper;
    private Date timeStamp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datanotificationlayout);
        Log.v("datanotificationsurvey", "inside datanotificationsurvey");

            dBHelper = new SmartDBHelper(this);
        timeStamp = new Date(DataNotification.when);
        // XML code stuff left out here, was not needed


    }

    public void submitNotify(int tempType, Date tempDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase dBH = dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userresponse", tempType);
        values.put("notifytime", (tempDate.getTime()/1000));
        dBH.insert("user_notify_data", null, values);
        dBH.close();
    }
}
```

---

```
// This is the event that is NOT working correctly
public class DataBuilder extends Activity {
    private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
    private SmartDataObject data;
    Context tThis;
    private SmartDBHelper dBHelper;
    private Date timeStampReference; //for keeping track of the first time

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("databuilder", "on create");
    dBHelper = new SmartDBHelper(this);
}

    public void prepareData(SmartDataObject temp) {
        submitData(temp);
    }

    public void submitData(SmartDataObject temp) {
        data = temp;
        System.out.println("Where: DB-submitData");
        try {
        SQLiteDatabase dBH = dBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // CODE FAILS AT THIS POINT
        Log.v("databuilder", "after writable");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("hr", data.getHeartRate());
        values.put("act", data.getAct());
        values.put("timestamp", data.getTimeStamp());
        dBH.insert("user_hr_data", null, values);
        Log.v("databuilder", "after insert");
        dBH.close();
        fireDataBuilderEvent(data);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void addDataBuilderListener(DataBuilderListener listener) {
        _listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public synchronized void removeDataBuilderListener(DataBuilderListener listener) {
        _listeners.remove(listener);
    }
    private synchronized void fireDataBuilderEvent(SmartDataObject temp) {
        DataBuilderEvent dRE = new DataBuilderEvent(this, temp);
        Iterator listeners = _listeners.iterator();
        while(listeners.hasNext()) {
            ((DataBuilderListener)listeners.next()).dataBuilderReceived(dRE);
        }
    }
    public interface DataBuilderListener {
        public void dataBuilderReceived(DataBuilderEvent event);
    }
}
```

---

```
// The error that is occuring.
03-13 17:38:40.130: INFO/System.out(279): Where: DB-submitData
03-13 17:38:40.130: WARN/System.err(279): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 17:38:40.151: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataBuilder.submitData(DataBuilder.java:41)
03-13 17:38:40.151: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataBuilder.prepareData(DataBuilder.java:34)
03-13 17:38:40.171: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$2.dataAnalyzedReceived(SmartApp.java:56)
03-13 17:38:40.171: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.fireDataAnalyzedEvent(DataRobot.java:269)
03-13 17:38:40.181: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.analyzeData(DataRobot.java:79)
03-13 17:38:40.181: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$1.dataReceivedReceived(SmartApp.java:49)
03-13 17:38:40.191: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.fireDataReceivedEvent(ConnectDevice.java:79)
03-13 17:38:40.201: WARN/System.err(279):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.run(ConnectDevice.java:46)
03-13 17:38:40.211: WARN/System.err(279):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: Edit: I accidently saw a typo which wasn't. I have no idea why it doesn't work, mine is set up in pretty much the same fashion.

Comment: The OP has been updated with some changes mentioned by the posters below. Please advise on any problems you see. Thanks

Comment: I suffered from NullPointerExceptions at strange places while accessing the database before. It seems that sometimes garbage collector gets rid of my OpenHelper object when I don't access it immediately after creating (same with cursors, DO NOT pass cursors as a parameter from method to method EVER... NullPointerException. I have no idea why it happens, but it does). Workaround: before opening database, call: if(myOpenHelper==null) myOpenHelper = new MyOpenHelper(context); If there is another way to fix this I want to know it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick guess: change `private SmartDBHelper dBHelper = new SmartDBHelper(this);` to just `private SmartDBHelper dBHelper;` and only initialize the new object in onCreate().

Comment: I will look into that tonight and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Not working. Which onCreate method are you speaking of, just to make sure that i understand you correectly.

Comment: You can't use a reference to `this` before onCreate() is called, so try fixing both activities.

Comment: I see now. But i do not have an oncreate method in oncreate, suggestion there?

Comment: Made the modifications you said and here is the error that is happening. Please advise. Thanks, the updates are reflected in the original post.

Comment: This did not fix the problem, however, i am going to accept as the answer since this person attempted to assist me. I have found an alternative method for what i am trying to do, so resolving this problem is not crucial anymore. If someone posts something that will solve the problem in the future, i will change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

use SQLiteDatabase's methods to check the database status

isDbLockedByCurrentThread()
isDbLockedByOtherThreads

I think it's lock by another thread.
Or check your provider setting in Androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: If it is locked by another thread, how do i fix this issue? I will have to check these methods this evening. Just wanted to go ahead and see if you had an answer. Edit your original post if you need more room to explain. Just mark it as the part you edited and make a comment here telling me you edited. Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: How can i make those calls on the database when i am not able to get past the "SQLiteDatabase dBH = dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();" in my code. It gives me a null pointer exception at this point in my code. So, i will not be able to call methods on dBH.

Comment: Some modifications were made to the code, i updated them in the op. Let me know if you have any more ideas.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem... can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and while I wouldn't normally tell anyone to purposely leak anything, this was the only stable quick fix I could think of.

This fixed it for me;

`private static YourSQLiteOpenHelper helperAnchor;`

And in onCreate

`helperAnchor = this;`

So basically give the object a reference to itself to keep it alive because in my case there was nowhere else to sensibly put it due to calling my local db from a large number of classes in a ViewPager. This comes with the added downside of having to create another method to set it to null again, which you have to call wherever you want to clean it up.

But hey, it just werks. The application is super stable now where before it would crash on the SQLiteOpenHelper being null at random times. Please tell me if/when there's a better way to do it because quite frankly I don't like using this either.